# Is there a site on which Legendary is not the rarest badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-badges

On SO, only 172 people have [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary). Only [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal), with 184, is close to it in rarity. Only [6 people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary) have Legendary here on Meta. On Travel, it has never been awarded.

To spare me going through all 100+ sites to verify my hunch, can someone demonstrate either that it is the rarest badge (possibly tied at 0 with other rare badges) on every site in the network, or provide me a counter example?

Comment: Predict reversal becomes the rarest on SO, since we're much more close and delete-heavy now.

Comment: [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges) has one legendary, no reversal or unsung hero.

Comment: Legendary is not the rarest badge anymore - Constable, Sheriff, and Illuminator :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/719894/rarity-of-two-badges-compared-over-sites?badge1=Illuminator&badge2=Legendary), the [Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/248/illuminator) badge is (much) rarer than Legendary on most sites; of course, there are exceptions, but there's just a handful of them. You can edit the query parameters to compare other badges.

[image]

Comment: I guess Legendary is even commoner now after the question rep change, while Illuminator frequency wouldn't have changed at all due to that.

Answer (score 10):

It is not the rarest badge on every site.

Over on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), it [has been awarded once](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/146/legendary), whereas [Tenacious](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/183/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/184/unsung-hero) have never been awarded. There are similar situations with those badges, or Reversal, on other sites as well. [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges) was mentioned in the comments, and I also spotted it on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges).